# bad operand types for binary operator. i am getting that error for the below program. please explain why?

Tags: java, oop

```
public class MotorCar extends Vehicle
{
    private String engCap;

    public double getLicenseFee()
    {
        double fee;

        if(this.engCap < "1500cc")
        {
            return fee = 750;
        }
        else if(this.engCap > "1500cc" && this.engCap < "2500cc")
        {
            return fee = 900;
        }
        else(this.engCap > "2500cc")
        {
            return fee = 1250;
        }

    }

}
```

what is wrong with this?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Please post your full error and what you're attempting to do.

Comment: Oh ic what the OP is trying to do... He wants to parse those strings as numbers and assign a different fee depending on the range.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot compare strings (or any other objects) using the less-than `<` and greater-than `>` operators.

If you change your engCap variable to an int and drop the "cc" portion, you'll be able to compare it the way you're attempting to.

For example:

```
public class MotorCar extends Vehicle {
    private int engCap;

    public double getLicenseFee() {
        double fee;

        if(this.engCap < 1500) {
            return fee = 750;
        } else if(this.engCap > 1500 && this.engCap < 2500) {
            return fee = 900;
        } else(this.engCap > 2500) {
            return fee = 1250;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Java, you cannot use the "<" and ">" (and "<=" and ">=") operators on Strings.  To compare the values, use the [`String#compareTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29) method, which will return an integer less than zero, equal to zero, or greater than zero, depending on if the String compares less than equal to, or greater than the argument.

Be careful, because this is string comparison, "500cc" will be greater than "1500cc".

**EDIT**

If you are attempting to determine a range based on the integer portion of `engCap`, then it would be simpler to go with @thegrinner's answer, and just store the numeric value without the "cc".  Then you could use the operators you're attempting to use.